# i3 wm bindsym exec debug

Tags: keyboard, i3-window-manager

Is there any way to see what is happening when bindsym exec fails. I just get certain scripts fail silently and it would be great to see some sort of output in order to debug my config.

For example, if I `bindsym $mod+o exec --no-startup-id {some script}` it fails if I run it via shortcut. But If I run it from the terminal it works. I need to see what is happening in the background when $mod+o is pressed in order to diagnose the problem.

Can't it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also having this problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: Have you tried that? https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/8o0vuq/how_do_i_debug_a_script_that_is_executed_from_an/